# Debian VMWARE 10.0.2 can't connect fully to the internet

Tags: debian, dns

Yesterday I made a single Windows user account. I have been using VMvare for two years now, never had problems with It. Suddenly my user couldn't access the internet, so I started browsing about It, but didn't find any useful information. Then my root account couldn't connect to the internet...

I started reconfiguring the NAT stuffs, this is how It looks:

Configuration:

[image: cfg]

NAT:

[image: nat]

I can ping any server ip, but can't ping domains. It doesn't get resolved. I also can't connect to my RDP, but I have the port forwarded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add Google **DNS** Servers (**8.8.8.8** and **8.8.4.4**) in your Windows Ethernet card options :)

Comment: Do DNSes have to be the ones from Google? I guess not. The answer would be better if it covered this issue.

Comment: It did, cuz It works. He is totally right. The answer is totally fine, don't be ashamed cuz u didn't know It.